# If statements and 2D array in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a table on excel, and I would like to check if some element is empty, for misstyping or whatelse.

So, I want to check all of elements which are placed at [1].

```
import csv
matrix = csv.reader(open("matrix1.csv","rb"))

arr = range(50)

x = 0
for row in matrix:
    arr[x] = row
    x += 1

i = 0
len = len(arr)
for i in range(len):
    if ((arr[i][1]) is None):
        print("it is empty")
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

But, if i code like my code below, it works, but my console still says:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
for i in range(len):
    if ((arr[i]) != 0):
        print(arr[i][1])
```

Full console output:

> 585957
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   545253
>   515359
>   575951
>     File "C:/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 17, in 
>   525356
>       print(arr[i][1])
>   565958
>   585754
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>   505152
>   535250

It means, it gives me the elements I want, but it is still not cool.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `arr[i]` is an integer. You can't take the 1st index of an integer, so try `print(arr[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to instantiate a list of fixed length with `arr = range(50)`. For the majority of Python applications, you don't need to concern yourself with this; lists can grow dynamically and memory will be allocated as needed. Instead, just make an empty list and append to it.

```
arr = []

for row in matrix:
    arr.append(row)
```

I think your error comes from the fact that you might not be replacing all of the elements in `range(50)` with rows of your matrix, leaving behind integer values. These then result in the error you see (`49[1]` is not valid, since you try to index an integer).

Comment: You right!! Thank you, now it is working, I am sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is a single dimensional array, or simply a list, that contains the numbers from `0` to `49`. `arr[i][1]` is trying to access the second item (`1`) in the `i+1`th list of `arr`, which doesn't exist, becuase the `i+1`th item of `arr` is a number, and not a list (it's the number `i`).

Comment: Now I look more, there's issues upstream. The OP presumably is trying to instantiate a list of fixed size with `arr = range(50)`. They should instead use `arr = []` and append to it. The error could well come from the fact that they don't replace all elements of `arr`, leaving behind some integers. `arr[x] = row` suggests they are trying to replace integers with lists inside that `for` loop.

Comment: @roganjosh You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I preferred to give this OP time to adapt the answer beyond the obvious to avoid multiple answers, but that's not happened so I'll do that now

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate your explanation, I just fixed it! Thank you!!